# jquery numeric validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I use the following function for **numeric validation not allowing special character** and alphabet,It was working fine.If I copy and paste the value to the text box it the values are missing .

For example ,I copy the value **12-3456-789** and paste into the validation text box,pasted only **1234567** instead of 123456789

```
$( "input[type=text]" ).on("keyup", function() {
  var o=$(this);
  o.val(o.val().replace(/[^\d]/g,""));
});
```

Comment: Why do you need the `[]`?

Comment: Can you show your HTML? My guess is, you've got the `maxlength` attribute set to `9` on your `input` element.

Comment: @Itay am not familiar with regular expression

Comment: Seems to be working: http://jsfiddle.net/qQkf2/ **NOTE** Regex slightly changed.

Comment: @User Your code works for me

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work, I tried also copy-pasting your test string. 
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5CkS/)

Probably your error resides in HTML code!

HTML:

```
<input type="text" />
```

JS:

```
$( "input[type=text]" ).on("keyup", function() {
  var o=$(this);
  o.val(o.val().replace(/[^\d]/g,""));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should works. As @Kemal Fadillah suggestion, it'll not works if you have `maxlength` attribute set to `9` in your input

```
<input type="text" maxlength="9" />
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/54Met/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

It's work fine only [check the Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S8MYz/2/) `show you can remove maxlength on your input text feald`

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is a example that works for both paste and keyup
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/537jc/1/)

```
$("[id$=textTest]").bind("focusout", function (e) {
    $("[id$=textTest]").val($("[id$=textTest]").val().replace(/[^0-9]+/g, ""));
});

$("[id$=textTest]").bind("keyup", function (e) {
    $("[id$=textTest]").val($("[id$=textTest]").val().replace(/[^0-9]+/g, ""));
});
```